# how to get multiple select(ed) list values from template?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Trying to figure out a way to this, here's the code, in a template I have:

```
<template name="main">
  <select name="foo" multiple>
   {{each users}}
    {{>userinfo}}
   {{/each}}
  </select>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Add to team</button>
</template>

<template name="userinfo">
  <option value={{_id}}>{{username}}</option>
</template>
```

So that creates a multiple selectable list, but how in my Meteor JS code do I get these multiple values and do something with them? I know I'm probably going to be doing something in Template.main.events but I'm stuck there, I know in pure JQuery I'd do something like:

```
var users = [];
$('#foo :selected').each(function(i, selected){
  users[i] = $(selected).text();
});
```

Just not sure how to implement this in the Meteor events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wrap your elements inside of a `<form></form>`, then you can catch the `submit` [event](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_events) like so:

```
Template.main.events({
  submit: function() {
    // jquery code here to extract the values
    return false;
  }
});
```

Before the `return false` (so the event doesn't bubble up and refresh the page), you can use your jQuery code to extract the ids.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to use a form you can just listen for a click event on the button itself:

```
Template.main.events({
  'click #add-to-team': function() {
    // jquery code here to extract the values
  }
});
```

Comment: is it necessary to wrap it in <form> tags? why can't I just do the submit event without the form tags?

Comment: There has been a long discussion about this over at meteor-talk google group. It seems many people have already discarded the form tag since they represent the request/response model whereas meteor employs the reactive model where you can for example, update field just on keyup on the field's input. So perhaps you should update your answer to reflect the fact that one can grab any *event* and do whatever they want with it, event not being restricted to, not even requiring, form events.

Comment: so I don't need it then? can't I just, for the event, go something like 'click submit' instead?

Comment: @JasonIp Yes, you can just use a click event also. :)

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy Updated - Thanks for the info. For now I'll probably stick with form elements in my own code, if for no other reason than it helps our css framework do the right thing.

Comment: @DavidWeldon I'm also inclined to use the form tags for both semanticity and readable code structure, but I guess you and I are not the majority :)

Answer (score 1):

Got it, all I had to do was something like so:

```
Template.main.events({
  'click #addToTeam' : function () {
    var array_of_values = $('#foo').val();
    //do something with array_of_values
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Jason since @DavidWeldon's answer works for you, why don't you go ahead and mark it as the accepted answer so that anyone who reads this post later on will know where to look at.